# Type equality in Dart - strange behavior

Tags: dart, types

I was doing some testing on type equality in Dart with version 2.14.4.
I run the following test:

```dart
  test('Type test', () {
      Type _detectType<T>() => T;
      var nullableStringType = _detectType<String?>();
      var doubleType = _detectType<double>();
      expect(doubleType == nullableStringType, isFalse);
      expect(doubleType.hashCode == nullableStringType.hashCode, isFalse);
    });
```

I was quite surprised discovering that the last test failed.
In my understanding two different (i.e. not equal) objects should have different hashCode.
Should I consider this a bug or there is an hidden logic that I couldn't get?

Comment: The point of a hash function is to map a potentially large space of possible values to a smaller set of values, usually to make lookups efficient or to make one-way data transformations.  The [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) means that [hash collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision) are necessarily possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug. There is no requirement for unequal objects to have different hash codes as evidenced by the docs for [`hashCode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html).

> Objects that are not equal are allowed to have the same hash code. It is even technically allowed that all instances have the same hash code, but if clashes happen too often, it may reduce the efficiency of hash-based data structures like HashSet or HashMap.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't get this. I thought that different objects should have different hashCode.